# C# Run Task.RunSynchronously() on a different thread to where it was called

Tags: c#, wpf, task

I am working on a C# based automation desktop app (using WPF) and I have encountered an issue.

The automation process is quite computationally intensive, and as such the WPF window is completely frozen by this.

And yes, I have looked at running the code asynchronously, but that causes more errors, as code is being run before it should be.

What I need is a way to run that code on a different thread to the UI, allowing the user to interact with it while the app is running.

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for a fire and forget method? Call Task.Run. This is the simplest way to do that. But is not recommended anyway.

Comment: Is that going to run all the functions in order and wait for them to finish before the next one starts?

Comment: You can try and play with Task.WaitAll() https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall?view=net-6.0

Comment: Please add more details and let us know what you mean by "Async is causing more errors".  Consider having a Thread or Task Field, rather than spawning them on user input, if the task is long running. also you may look at creating you own BackgroundWorker if Queueing is desired.

Comment: @JackHolman , you could also share your code to help us better understand what you really want to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answer depends on whether you need to push results back to UI thread or not.

If not - use TPL, `Parallel.For`/`ForEach` to process collections in parallel. Methods returns `ParallelLoopResult`, which allows to check state of computation. See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel?view=net-6.0)

Other way, as mentioned in comments, is to use `Task` - `Task.WhenAll`/`Task.WaitAll`. While `WaitAll` is essentially synchronous and still will freeze your app, `WhenAll` is not. I guess problems you get are related to accessing UI from non-main thread, which requires using `Dispatcher` (there is a method to queue Action to be ran on main thread). General advice - first `await Task.WhenAll(...)`, then work with UI.

Also, see [this article](https://igorpopov.io/2018/06/16/asynchronous-programming-in-csharp-with-wpf/) for more clues.

Answer (score 0):

As it would turn out, I was accessing the UI from the second thread, which according to WPF is a big nono.